# Server and client-side validation at once with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

### The goal

Creating model's validation once and use it both for the model and for the view.

### The problem

I don't know the way.

### The scenario

I'm creating an application in Ruby on Rails and I want to indicate that User's e-mail always will require at least 6 characteres to vaildate it, and I want to use that rule for client-side and server-side.

### What I actually need

A light. A start. I just have the user in the database and the model in Rails.

**How to?**

Answer (score 0):

There is a `gem client_side_validations` which is no longer being maintained but appears to do what you want. ([github link](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations))

Comment: Having used this, I can tell you there's a reason it's not being maintained.  If you need powerful client-side validation, use a client-side framework (Angular, Ember, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use rails4_client_side_validations. It supports rails 4 also. [rails4_client_side_validations](https://github.com/kalkov/rails4_client_side_validations)

Comment: Authored… eleven months ago. Yikes.